# SQL Insert Into Where Record Not Exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I have an automated process that appends data into `Table1` every week. It only has 4 columns `[Reason, Number of Occurences, Sent Date, and Program]`. `Table1` keeps growing and does not care about duplicate records. (There are only 26 Records each week and only 4 columns so performance/space is not an issue)

I have another table `Table2` that I only want Distinct Records from `Table1`. If the record already exists in `Table 2` I do not want to insert the record.
I thought the below Statement would work, but it does not:

```
begin transaction
insert into [Database]..[Table2]
select Distinct * from [Database]..[Table1]
where not exists (select * from [Database]..[Table2])

(0 row(s) affected)
```

If I comment out the WHERE clause, it will work, but it will insert records that already exist in `Table2`

```
begin transaction
    insert into [Database]..[Table2]
    select Distinct * from [Database]..[Table1]
    --where not exists (select * from [Database]..[Table2])

(83 row(s) affected)
```

How do I check for Distinct Records in `Table1` and if that record does not already exist in `Table2`, insert that record?

I am Using MS SQL Server Version 11.0.6020.0

Comment: IMO if you used an IF statement, what you're doing would be much more readable.

Comment: Do you really need to have two tables -- why not just have table2 be a view into table1?

Comment: @Hogan, ya know what... That actually may be an option. I'll bring it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would use `except`.  Assuming the tables have the same columns:

```
insert into [Database]..[Table2]
    select Distinct t1.*
    from [Database]..[Table1] t1
    except
    select t2.*
    from [Database]..[Table2] t2;
```

Your `not exists` clause is not correlated to the data in `table1`, so it is not doing what you expect.

Comment: thank you. Didn't know that EXCEPT was the thing to use. Is this solely a MS SQL Server thing, or can you use this in things like Oracle as well? Would you also be so kind to link any documentation? Can't seem to find this, hence the StackOverflow Question.

Comment: @MattR . . . The idea is supported in several databases.  Sometimes it is called `MINUS`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use MERGE statement as well which will have only one condition WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET then you will directly insert the row in target table.

Note: Please consider DISTINCT rows from Source table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra WHERE clause in your inner select to compare table2 and table1 records :

```
begin transaction
insert into [Database]..[Table2]
select Distinct * from [Database]..[Table1] t1
where not exists (
  select * from [Database]..[Table2] t2 
  where t1.reason=t2.reason 
    AND t1.occurences=t2.occurences 
    AND t1.sent_date=t2.sent_date 
    AND t1.program=t2.program
)
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, but it seems like a lot of code for a simple task.

Comment: if the volume of records is insignificant and as you dont seem to keep any trace of the technical dates (creaton or update of the records) you may also,TRUNCATE table 2 and then use a simple INSERT INTO table2 SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1

Comment: That is a valid point, I thought of that as well. But the rest of my team didn't like that idea. But good point nonetheless.